Python - check for specific shell prompt on a remote server
Is there a way, using Python, to check for a specific command prompt on a remote Unix server.  I need to be able to SSH to a series of remote Unix servers, check that I receive a "INPUT NAME:" prompt, and log off.  I don't need to enter anything at the prompt, just make sure that one is received.  I haven't a clue how to go about it, and every combination of search terms I've tried just gives me how to get input from a user(which I already know how to do).  The pseudocode I have looks like this:
Iterate through server list
SSH log in to Unix server
Did you get an "INPUT NAME:" prompt after login?
     True: Mark Server good
     False: Mark Server bad
Close connection
Next server

To clarify, the "INPUT NAME:" prompt is part of a proprietary shell that users with a certain group get assigned upon login, as opposed to something like bash or ksh.  What I will be doing is creating an ID with this group as a test ID for this purpose.

I don't think SSH starts an interactive shell, so it won't create a prompt either. That means you'd need to start one yourself. Perhaps, you could just check the environment vars that control the shell prompt instead. What do you need this for? "INPUT NAME" doesn't really look like a shell prompt, btw, but rather a prompt by some interactive shell script.

You could try input(“Input Name: ”) or stdin to read the terminal.

I edited my original post for clarity.  @UlrichEckhardt - When an SSH session is started to these servers, normal users get dropped into a proprietary, restricted shell session that only allows them to interact with some user information files.  "INPUT USER:" is the prompt they are given in the terminal, rather than something like '[user@serverIP]:".

What you need is pexpect. Look it up.

Here is a suggestion: Use pexpect.pxssh. To get started, create a Python virtualenv using venv or other tools. Then install pexpect:
pip install pexpect

Here is a sample code which connects to a single server. You can add a loop so it will work with multiple servers:
import pexpect.pxssh

# Start a ssh session
server_name = "ubuntu"
user_name = "root"
ssh = pexpect.pxssh.pxssh(encoding="utf-8")
ssh.login(server=server_name, username=user_name)

# Check for the prompt
# The .before attribute holds text before the next interaction
print(f"{ssh.before=}")
is_good = "INPUT NAME:" in ssh.before
print(f"{is_good=}")
ssh.logout()

Here is a sample output:
ssh.before=" unset PROMPT_COMMAND\r\n\x1b]0;root@localhost: ~\x07root@localhost:~# PS1='[PEXPECT]\\$ '\r\n"
is_good=False

Notes

Look up the .login() function in case you need password, or additional parameters
Try to get it to work with a single server first before you add a loop. That way it is easier to troubleshoot
Doc: https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pxssh.html


Thank you so much.  I believe that is exactly what I needed.
